Longest Subarray with Maximum Bitwise AND
This is based on a problem from LeetCode  (#2419) Longest Subarray with Maximum Bitwise AND
I'm not concerned with the logic related to the problem (I need to find the longest chain of maximum elements (max of array)). Here's my solution -
    max_index = nums.index(max(nums))
    max_val = max(nums)
    ans, temp = 1, 1
    for i in range(max_index+1, len(nums)):
        if (nums[i]==max_val):
            temp+=1
        else:
            ans = max(ans, temp)
            temp=1
    ans = max(ans, temp)
    return ans

This fetches me a wrong answer in one of the test cases where the length of the array is fairly large - 
The expected answer is 125, whereas my code fetches me an answer of 126. What can be the problem with my code that causes it to fail for a large test case? I felt I had accounted for all the edge cases possible (chain of max elements at the end of the array, equal length chains, etc.)

Bitwise AND on two operands (simplest case) returns a value which is less than or equal to the minimum of the 2 operands (according to my understanding). So, searching for the maximum element and checking if it's a part of a chain (contiguous subarray) should work, and we should return the length of the largest such subarray.

Yeah, I removed the comment already.

Unless I'm missing something, the bug is not specific to large test cases; it seems like [5, 3, 5] would have the same issue (returning 2 instead of 1).

temp=1 should be temp=0. this way when you're skipping elements, it's already 1, and when you find a new sequence, it becomes 2. Probably the problematic test is the first one where not the first sequence is the longest.

Ah yes, typical typo on my part. Typical overlooking as well. Thanks for correcting me.

Now it just feels silly to post this question.

Updating the code in the question
def longestSubarray(self, nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: int
    """
    max_index = nums.index(max(nums))
    max_val = max(nums)
    ans, temp = 1, 1
    for i in range(max_index+1, len(nums)):
        if (nums[i]==max_val):
            temp+=1
            ans = max(ans, temp)
        else:
            temp=0
    return ans

Approach

Find the maximum value in the array
Traverse the array, counting the consecutive element equal to the maximum value found in #1

It can be simplified if it can be done like
def longestSubarray(self, nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: int
    """
    max_val = max(nums)
    ans, temp = 0, 0
    for num in nums:
        if (num==max_val):
            temp+=1
            ans = max(ans, temp)
        else:
            temp=0
    return ans


Yeah. I just wanted to start checking from the first index pertaining to the maximum element, and I messed up with a typo. Not much difference though, this code has a runtime of 11 ms more compared to the case when you start from the max_index.

I meant simplify in terms of readability for the approach mentioned in the answer.

As an alternative, you can use itertools.groupby to get all consecutive runs of the same value.
def longestSubarray(self, nums: list[int]) -> int:
    from itertools import groupby
    mx = max(nums)
    return max(sum(1 for _ in g) for k, g in groupby(nums) if k == mx)


Great alternative solution!
